# Web App on Safari for iPad: Cancel touchstart on touchmove

Tags: jquery, ipad, scroll, touch

This might seem like a simple solution, but I am kinda of a n00b when it comes to this touch stuff on the iPad.

I understand the concept of what I need to do, I just don't know the syntax.

**Problem:** I have a page full of DIV's. These DIV's are wrapped in an iScroll4 wrapper. The iScroll script is set up nicely where if you were to start scrolling the page by tapping and moving a link, the link would never fire.

I, however, am not that good. Because I set up some jQuery code to animate one of the DIV's on "touchstart" but the problem is that even if I scroll or drag my finger, the animation fires even when I don't want it to.

I need to set a time out or cancel the touchstart. Or fire the animation on touchend, but cancel the touch if you drag your finger x amount of pixels and turn that touch into a touchmove.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Alex

EDIT: Here is my current jQuery code. I need to cancel the animation function from firing if I drag my finger X amount of pixels. Probably using pageX and pageY?

```
    $('tr#recent').live("touchend click", function () {
        $(".modalWindow").css('display', 'block').animate({
                height:716,
                top:15,
                left:15,
                width:995
            }, 300);            
    });
```

Here is how Yahoo does it with their Scrollview: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/scrollview/scrollview.html

```
var content = scrollView.get("contentBox"); 

content.delegate("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent links from navigating as part of a scroll gesture
    if (Math.abs(scrollView.lastScrolledAmt) > 2) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Y.log("Link behavior suppressed.")
    }
}, "a");
```

See how they are checking the "lastscrolled" amount and then canceling the link behavior if you drag your finger a certain distance.....But I am not using Scrollview....

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop the default event from firing then you need to cancel it. Have a read of the [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), especially event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation(). Another trick is to add false to the end of the function, so...

```
$( 'div' ).bind( 'touchstart', function(e)
{
    // do some funky stuff

    return false; // this'll cancel the default behaviour of the event
});
```

Usually, if you want to do some more stuff, you'd add another bind for 'touchmove' to get the X and Y of the movement.

Comment: Putting event.preventDefault and return false inside my function do nothing as far as stopping the animation from firing on touchend when I release my finger.

Comment: Right, so what you need to do is bind an event to mousemove and touchmove, in this event you then call stop() to the animation event.

Comment: That doesn't work because you can't stop an animation that hasn't started yet. I can only stop the animation after it's fired, and at that point it does me no good. Though I am closer to a solution now than I ever was...

Comment: So you don't want to fire the animation if the user has dragged and then released? Why not using the 'touchmove' event to set a variable that your animation function checks for. If it's false, it won't start the animation.

Comment: Yah that's what I am trying to do, I just don't know how to do that, haha.

Comment: Ha, ok, so you can see from my example how you can bind an event in jQuery, so once you've bound the event for touchmove, just create a variable outside the functions, say it's called fired, set that to true and then inside the bind function for the animation, check to see if the variable is true or not